# Unable to remove options from select with JavaScript iteration?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to remove options from a select input ("class") based on their classList depending on the selection made in a previous select input ("class-type"). Strangely enough, some options ARE removed (as they should be) when `enableClassSelect` is called, but not all options which don't have the necessary class are moved at once. Currently the "class-list" needs to be changed ~7 times before ALL options are removed (this should not happen!).

See code below - I've reviewed it several times and attempted some debugging to no avail. `console.log(classSelect.length);` prints "46", which is correct, so each option element should be checked in the iteration.

```js
function enableClassSelect(classType) {
  let classSelect = document.getElementById("class");
  console.log("Length: " + classSelect.length);
  for (i = 0; i < classSelect.length; i++) {
    if (!classSelect.options[i].classList.contains(classType)) {
      classSelect.remove(i);
    }
  }
  classSelect.disabled = false;
  classSelect.classList.remove("disabled-select");
  let classDefaultOption = document.getElementById("class-default-option");
  classDefaultOption.innerHTML = " -- select a class -- ";
  return;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="javascript:enableClassSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" class="reg" id="class-type" name="class-type" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select a class type -- </option>
  <option value="Magician">Magician</option>
  <option value="Thief">Thief</option>
  <option value="Warrior">Warrior</option>
  <option value="Bowman">Bowman</option>
  <option value="Pirate">Pirate</option>
</select>
<select class="disabled-select reg" id="class" name="class" disabled required>
  <option class="Magician Thief Warrior Bowman Pirate" id="class-default-option" disabled selected value></option>
  <!-- Magicians -->
  <option class="Magician" value="Battle Mage">Battle Mage</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Beast Tamer">Beast Tamer</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Blaze Wizard">Blaze Wizard</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Evan">Evan</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Kanna">Kanna</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Luminous">Luminous</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Bishop">Bishop</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Ice/Lightning Mage">Ice/Lightning Mage</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Fire/Poison Mage">Fire/Poison Mage</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Kinesis">Kinesis</option>
  <option class="Magician" value="Illium">Illium</option>
  <!-- Thieves -->
  <option class="Thief" value="Dual Blade">Dual Blade</option>
  <option class="Thief" value="Night Walker">Night Walker</option>
  <option class="Thief" value="Phantom">Phantom</option>
  <option class="Thief" value="Shadower">Shadower</option>
  <option class="Thief" value="Night Lord">Night Lord</option>
  <option class="Thief" value="Xenon">Xenon</option>
  <option class="Thief" value="Cadena">Cadena</option>
  <!-- Warriors -->
  <option class="Warrior" value="Aran">Aran</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Dawn Warrior">Dawn Warrior</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Demon Avenger">Demon Avenger</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Demon Slayer">Demon Slayer</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Hayato">Hayato</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Kaiser">Kaiser</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Mihile">Mihile</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Dark Knight">Dark Knight</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Hero">Hero</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Paladin">Paladin</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Zero">Zero</option>
  <option class="Warrior" value="Blaster">Blaster</option>
  <!-- Bowmen -->
  <option class="Bowman" value="Marksman">Marksman</option>
  <option class="Bowman" value="Bowmaster">Bowmaster</option>
  <option class="Bowman" value="Wild Hunter">Wild Hunter</option>
  <option class="Bowman" value="Wind Archer">Wind Archer</option>
  <option class="Bowman" value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option class="Bowman" value="Pathfinder">Pathfinder</option>
  <!-- Pirates -->
  <option class="Pirate" value="Angelic Buster">Angelic Buster</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Cannoneer">Cannoneer</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Jett">Jett</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Mechanic">Mechanic</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Buccaneer">Buccaneer</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Corsair">Corsair</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Shade">Shade</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Thunder Breaker">Thunder Breaker</option>
  <option class="Pirate" value="Ark">Ark</option>
</select>
```

**Expected**: select a class type (e.g. "Warrior" and the "class" element becomes enabled and displays the proper classes.

**Actual**: "class" options are removed seemingly at random over ~6 calls to `enableClassSelect` until the select element is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing it, not sure if it would be the fastest way, but it does work.

Essentially I removed all of the options from the HTML, and instead I am only adding on the correct options for that class type.

```js
function enableClassSelect(classType) {
  // Make sure the names of these are the same as the value for the options in the class-type select
  const magicians = ["Battle Mage", "Beast Tamer", "Blaze Wizard"];
  const thieves = ["Dual Blade", "Night Walker", "Phantom"];

  // Make sure theses are both in the same order
  const classTypesNames = ["magicians", "thieves"];
  const classTypes = [magicians, thieves];

  let classSelect = document.getElementById("class");

  // Clear the options from the classSelect, except for the default option
  var length = classSelect.options.length;
  if (length > 1) {
    for (i = classSelect.options.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      classSelect.remove(i);
    }
  }
  
  // Check the classtype they selected, and get the list of classes for that classType
  for (i = 0; i < classTypes.length; i++) {
    if (classType === classTypesNames[i]) {
      var classes = classTypes[i];

      for (j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
        // Create an option element with the class as the value
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.value = classes[j];
        opt.innerHTML = classes[j];

        classSelect.appendChild(opt);
      }
    }
  }

  classSelect.disabled = false;
  classSelect.classList.remove("disabled-select");

  return;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="javascript:enableClassSelect(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" class="reg" id="class-type" name="class-type" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select a class type -- </option>
  <option value="magicians">Magician</option>
  <option value="thieves">Thief</option>
</select>

<select class="disabled-select reg" id="class" name="class" disabled required>
  <option id="class-default-option" disabled selected value> -- select a class -- </option>
</select>
```

There needs to be a list for each classType that contains the classes for that classType.

```
const warriors = ["Aran", "Dawn Warrior", "Demon Avenger"];
```

Then add that classType to the list of classTypes:

```
const classTypesNames = ["magicians", "thieves", "warriors"];
const classTypes = [magicians, thieves, warriors];
```

This part "resets" the options for the classSelect so that only the default one remains:

```
var length = classSelect.options.length;
if (length > 1) {
  for (i = classSelect.options.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    classSelect.remove(i);
  }
}
```

From there the next section checks the value of the classType the user selected, and gets the list of classes for that classType, and creates option elements and appends them to the classSelect:

```
for (i = 0; i < classTypes.length; i++) {
  if (classType === classTypesNames[i]) {
    var classes = classTypes[i];

    for (j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
      // Create an option element with the class as the value
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = classes[j];
      opt.innerHTML = classes[j];

      classSelect.appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Callum, nice work-around! I'm going to hold off on accepting for now because I want to see if anyone out there can identify the problem with my method (it seems correct...). If nothing shows up in a few days I'll accept yours :)